# like in mui components make an asterisk before the text?

Tags: material-ui

like in mui components make an asterisk before the text?
The documentation doesn't say anything about it.

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/

Answer (score 0):

The documentation makes it very clear under `Input Adornments`. You can put whatever you want in the beginning or end of the text field using input adornments.

Sample code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

export default function InputAdornments() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
      <div>
        <TextField
          id="outlined-start-adornment"
          sx={{ m: 1, width: '25ch' }}
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">*</InputAdornment>,
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: read carefully what I need

Comment: @eeeMan You said you want an asterix before text. The above does this. So why dont you actually elaborate on what you actually need in more detail or an exmaple of what you are trying to achieve.